# what is the best way to sort chat room by most recent chat on each room

Tags: mysql

I have a chat_hist table with structure as follow:

```
|chat_id (auto increment)|room_id(int)|sender_id(int)|messege(text)|timestamp|
```

so what is the best way (performance wise) to list `chat_room`(`room_id`) based on most recent `chat`(`timestamp`) from each `chat_room` (just like list on Whatsapp group)?

I am asking this since I am no DB expert and I imagine that the chat message in each room growing what happen the performance when each user refresh the most recent list

what i use for now is this:

```
select room_id from (
    select room_id,max(time_stamp) as ts from chat_hist where room_id in (
        select distinct room_id from chat_room
    )
    group by room_id
) as A order by ts desc
```

where table `chat_room` is where all the `room_id` reside.

So what is the best way to do this...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chat_id autoincrements.  So presumably it goes up as timestamp goes up.

Therefore, you can find the latest row in chat_hist for each room_id like this

```
            SELECT room_id, MAX(chat_id) chat_id
              FROM chat_hist
             GROUP BY room_id
```

If you have an index on `room_id` this subquery will be *very* fast; it uses a so-called *loose index scan.*

Then, you can use that as a subquery to grab the latest chat detail for each room:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM chat_hist c
  JOIN (
            SELECT room_id, MAX(chat_id) chat_id
              FROM chat_hist
             GROUP BY room_id

       ) latest ON c.chat_id = latest.chat_id
```

Comment: If you're not using room_id then you can omit it from the select

Comment: Sure, you are right.  But the query planner factors it out.  I included it for clarity of exposition, not for coding necessity.